# Containers within kubernetes deployment do not use hostNetwork

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I've got familiar with kubernetes very recently. I want to deploy a project into my minikube cluster. Here is the yaml file:

*deployment.yml*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: project
  name: project
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: project
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: project
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: container1
        image: image1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      - name: container2
        image: image2
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

I created the deployment successfully, and both containers in a pod are up and running but these containers can not connect to local resources like databases(e.g. redis)

I get logs via this command and the resut is as below.

kubectl logs -f project-5f5c6df6bc-q82s5 container1

> *Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.*

Comment: I'd separately deploy Redis and your other dependencies inside Kubernetes (maybe using a prebuilt Helm chart).  You also need to include `env:` settings to tell the application where the Redis actually is.  Kubernetes is designed as a self-contained multi-node system, and you wouldn't want your application to pick a random data store based on which node it gets deployed to (and for that matter you wouldn't want to deploy a standalone Redis on each node).

Comment: Thank you so much. So in which situations we use hostNetwork: true?

Comment: I'd only consider it in a DaemonSet which will run one replica on every node, and then for infrastructure software I wanted to manage in Kubernetes rather than a different automation tool.  Even then, I don't think I've ever actually used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a Service of type `ExternalName` with the special hostname provided by Minikube:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#hostminikubeinternal
This exposes an external Service that can be consumed from Kubernetes.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: host.minikube.internal
```

In the code that runs in the cluster simply use the host `redis` so that Kubernetes can retrieve the mapping to the desired host.